# Scipy function muliple arguments

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have this function:

```
def error(w0, w1):
    return sum((data.Height - (w1*data.Weight+w0))**2)
```

and next I want to optimize it with`res = scipy.optimize.minimize(error, (1, 2), ...`

When I try to run it, I have error:`TypeError: error() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

I find what this error doesn't apper when I change my function to:

```
def error(w):
    return sum((data.Height - (w[1]*data.Weight+w[0]))**2)
```

But I want to understand why my first doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you look at the documentation of this function, it says that

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=(), method=None, jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, constraints=(), tol=None, callback=None, options=None)[source]
```

fun is your function here and args are the arguments that you are sending. Now in your first code your objective function has 2 parameters but what you are sending is a tuple and thats what should be done according to the documentation.

So in short what you are sending to the objective function is a tuple but there are 2 parameters over there, and thats why the error pops up.

And for the same reason your second code works as `w` is just a tuple here and thus the code works!

Answer (score 0):

```
minimize(fun, x0, args=(), method=None,....):
"""
 minimize f(x) subject to
   ...
    where x is a vector of one or more variables.
```

So the first argument is your function, `error`, and the 2nd is `x0`, in your case a tuple, the initial guess.  and the first the code does is turn `x0` into an array, `x0 = np.asarray(x0)`.

And look at an example function:

```
fun = lambda x: (x[0] - 1)**2 + (x[1] - 2.5)**2
```

I haven't used this much, but it sure looks like your function should work if you did:

```
error(np.array([1,2]))
```

That's consistent with your 2nd form, but not the first.

To put it another way, `minimize` works by starting with the initial value, `np.array(x0)`, plugs that into `error`, and based on the return value tries other 2 element arrays, variations on that initial `x0`.  It's not playing with multiple arguments, but with one argument with multiple elements.